i am unable to create react app using the command 'npx create-react-app my-app' there is error occuring everytime when i try to create app
PS F:\reactproject> npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in F:\reactproject\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm error code ECONNRESET
npm error syscall read
npm error errno ECONNRESET
npm error network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/electron-to-chromium: read ECONNRESET
npm error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm error network
npm error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\NASEER PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-06T06_52_01_032Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from F:\reactproject
Done.

i was just trying to learn react.js and i have just started to practise but this error came in firts time road map i was stuck in this error and unable to solve it

Where are you located, and do you have a stable internet connection? It looks like you can't reach https://registry.npmjs.org/ properly.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

error cause
ECONNRESET error can cause the connection to be terminated on the server side, and the network is unstable so you can't be embarrassed.
error resolution
Check if your internet is unstable.
Try rebooting your computer and try again
